# Why do large PCB traces have solder points/islands/stripes on them?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, monitor

[image: SolderedGridImage]
This is from a power supply for an old PC monitor. I opened it up to see if I could fix it (likely bad caps) and saw this rectangle matrix. What's the purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably an attempt to reduce the resistance of the trace (and better dissipate heat) by putting solder in parallel.

The pattern in the solder mask is likely so that a solid section of solder does not warp the board excessively as it cools (the [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#Coefficient_of_thermal_expansion) of solder is much higher than that of FR4).

You can see shorter traces to the right that are covered almost entirely by solder.

Comment: More likely heat exchange than electrical resistance, though why they would do that under a cap I have no idea.

Comment: Dave Jones of EEVBlog tested this and found that the solder reduces trace resistance by about 50%. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9q5vwCESEQ